# Repeat text + n times with google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

**Input:**

testing 18

**Output Goal:**

testing1
testing2
testing3
testing4
testing5
....
testing18

Cant seem to get them to count as it print out 18 times.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(,REPT(B33&"±",C33)),"±")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B33&ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,C33)))
```